# passing image from one activity to other activity android

Tags: android

In first activity

```
intent.putExtra("image",lists.getImageUri());
```

in second activity:

```
imag.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("image",00));
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: i'm using this to transfer image,but this is not working for me,i'm new in android .

Comment: Put this in the question itself, and be more specific on why it does not work. "It's not working" is not a problem statement.

Comment: sir,,the problem here is that the image is missing in second activity..when i click on any item in first activity.....And i have double checked all the reference still it remains same.

Answer (score 1):

First Activity

```
Intent.putExtra("image",lists.getImageUri());
```

Second Activity

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
ImageView imageView =(ImageView)
findViewById(R.id.imageView);        strImage=String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("Image");    ImageView.setImageResource(strImage);
```

Comment: thanks it works with some changes...                                                               Intent intent= getIntent();
         String strImage=String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("image"));
        Glide.with(this).load(strImage).into(imag);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `putExtra` for passing a single image uri to Intent. You can use `setData` like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setData(lists.getImageUri());
```

then you can get the uri in the second activity with:

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
imag.setImageURI(uri);
```